# Can `bpf_probe_write_user` cause segmentation fault?

Tags: linux, memory-management, segmentation-fault, ebpf, uprobe

I am using `bpf_probe_write_user` to overwrite the argument of a function in an ebpf uprobe. When the argument that I have to overwrite is small, and the data I am overwriting the argument is big, a segmentation fault occurs. Is this something that can be solved?